# How not to get spammed with mouseover and mouseout (by time)?

Tags: javascript

https://jsfiddle.net/0bt3hy29/6/

```
function chandgeBackgroundImageOnMouse() {
    house.addEventListener("mouseover", ()=>{
        bgImage.style.backgroundImage = home
        is_paused = true
})
    house.addEventListener("mouseout", ()=>{
        is_paused = false
    })
}
```

When you mouseover the "house" element and then mouseout it - everything is working as should. But if you will mouseover and mouseout very quickly - auto slider will be broken.

So, i see 2 choises.

1. To make react only after a gap of 3 seconds (it's mouseover and then mouseout - only after 3 seconds it can be mouseover one more time)
2. To make react only when picture was changed (it's mouseover, then mouseout - and only after picture was changed it can be mouseover one more time)

Comment: I tried also to make it with `if` `if(bgImage.style.backgroundImage == data[1]){
     console.log(1)
    }` but nothing had happend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is recursive with interval so its recursvevly creating new instances of many things. Instead, try this.

```
    const car = "url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1580273916550-e323be2ae537?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=464&q=80')"
const home = "url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1600596542815-ffad4c1539a9?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1175&q=80')"
const candles = "url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1593542468714-ac3ba4b38d43?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1169&q=80')"
const data = [
car,
home,
candles,
]

const house = document.querySelector('#house')
const avto = document.querySelector('#avto')
const bgImage = document.querySelector('.img-of-dog')

let current = 0;

function intervalMethod(){
        bgImage.style.backgroundImage = data[current]
        current = ++current % data.length
}

let changeTimeset = setInterval(()=>{
        intervalMethod();
    }, 2000)
  
  
house.addEventListener("mouseover", ()=>{
     clearInterval(changeTimeset);
          bgImage.style.backgroundImage = home
    })
house.addEventListener("mouseout", ()=>{
     changeTimeset = setInterval(()=>{
        intervalMethod();
         }, 2000)
        })
```